# Count number of times data is repeated in a column and show number in another column?

Tags: vba, excel, count

I have a UserForm that finds and copies a range of data and pastes it along with new data from the UserForm into a different sheet. I am wanting for it to also count the number of times some of that data is repeated in the new sheet. I have tried several different approches but none are working. Right now this is what I have:

```
.Range("I1").Value = iVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A3:A103"), "CrisisNameTextBox1.Value")
```

This puts "TRUE" in the corresponding cell instead of the number of times the data is repeated.

Comment: You have 2 `=` that is making it think the value should be an operation if they are equal

Comment: Still a VBA noob, I don't know how to write it without both =. Is there another command I can use?

Comment: `iVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A3:A103"), CrisisNameTextBox1.Value)` followed by `.Range("I1").Value = iVal` or, if you don't need the `iVal` value for anything else, just use `.Range("I1").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A3:A103"), CrisisNameTextBox1.Value)`

Comment: Note: with the double-quotation marks around `CrisisNameTextBox1.Value` your code would be counting up how many times the actual string "CrisisNameTextBox1.Value" exists within the range - my previous comment assumes you want to find how many times the `Value` of the `TextBox` exists within that range.

Comment: YowE3K, your first suggestion looks like what I tried my first time around. Both that and your second suggestion only put a 1 for the count no matter how many times the data is repeated. It feels like there should be a simple answer... I just am at a loss for that answer.

Comment: Are you trying to find how many times each value in A:A exists (in which case a solution such as @Sirmyself suggested would work - place `=COUNTIF($A$3:$A$103,$A3)` in cell I3 and copy down, or use the VBA formula `Range("I3:I103").FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(R3C1:R103C1,RC1)"`) or are you trying to find how many times a specific value (as identified by `CrisisNameTextBox1.Value`) exists in the range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably could use this function in the corresponding cell:

```
    =COUNTIF( [range], [cell] )
```

The [*range*] is the range you want to check (use $ to make sure its value does not change from one cell to another)

The [*cell*] is the cell you are currently checking.

Assign the function to the cells you want and it should work

If you want to drag/copy this formula from one cell to an other : use the $ character to lock the coordinates you don't want to be changed. I.e :

- `$A1` Will prevent the *column* from being changed, but will allow the row
- `A$1` Will prevent the *row* from being changed, but will allow the column
- `$A$1` Will prevent both coordinates from being changed

The same applies to ranges (`$A1:$F15`, `$A1:F1`, `$A$1:F15`, `A1:$F15`, etc.)

Comment: The trouble with that solution is the value that is being searched for will need to be written to a cell.  At the moment, it is probably just local to the UserForm.

Comment: Original poster said he was copying data from one sheet to another, so I guess we can assume he also has those data in a cell.

Comment: this works if I use =COUNTIF(A3:A103,A3) but I have to manually change every occurance of the formula or the range changes. Just a tedious way to do it lol.

Comment: If it looks stupid but it works... I ain't stupid! ^^